# Flutter BLoC - Implementing Pop Up Confirmation for Unsaved Form Changes during Navigation

Tags: bloc

I'm building a Flutter app using the BLoC pattern, and I have a form on one of the screens. I'd like to implement a feature where, if the user hasn't saved the form, a Pop Up should appear before navigating to another screen, giving the option to save changes.

My BLoC setup includes a method to check if the form is saved or not. Now, I need help on how to display a Pop Up when the user attempts to navigate away from the screen, ensuring navigation proceeds only after the user decides.

Could anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this functionality?

> This code is how i keep the state of save:

```
class AppbarSaveActionCubit extends Cubit<AppbarSaveActionState> 
{
AppbarSaveActionCubit() : super(AppbarSaveActionState.initial());

// action to save from a bottom bar to a child widget 
void saveAction(){
final newState = state.copyWith(saveAction: true);
emit(newState);
// inicializar el estado del cubit
emit(AppbarSaveActionState.initial());
}

// action to save from a bottom bar to a child widget 
void saveActionInitState(){
final newState = state.copyWith(saveAction: false);
emit(newState);
}

// action to back page from a bottom bar parent widget action 
over a child widget
void backPageAction(){
final newState = state.copyWith(backAction: true);
emit(newState);
// inicializar el estado del cubit
emit(AppbarSaveActionState.initial());
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When your bloc decides that you want to display the popup, set some flag in your state to indicate that.  In the UI, use the listener of a BlocConsumer to watch for that flag and display your popup.